# How to loop through the body of a website using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iteration, screen-scraping

first off, my python knowledge is extremely rudimentary, so apologies if what i'm asking is really stupid, but here goes.

I'm trying to use selenium, to read through boards (particularly /biz/'s catalog on 4chan) to track keywords for projects I'm invested in and notify me when there's a thread discussing one of my projects.

so far I've managed to open the page and locate the elements I want to search through, using:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver  = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('https://boards.4channel.org/biz/catalog')

threads = driver.find_element_by_id('threads').text

print(threads)
driver.quit()
```

this successfully prints out all of the threads as text, but now I want to iterate through them and only return the lines that contain the keywords "NFY" and "CORX". I've been testing with the keyword "DOGE", because mine are rarely mentioned. What's the best way to iterate through this text and only return the lines containing my keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the thread, this should work.

```
threads = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("Path to individual threads")

searchText = ["DOGE", "NFY", "CORX"]

for t in searchText.lower():
    for i in range(len(threads)):
        if t in threads[i].text.lower():
            print(f"Thread: {threads[i].text}")
```

Comment: Hi Jennifer, thanks for the reply. Basically want to return the line that contains any of the keywords, and ideally if I can return the thread ID, i'd like to have the program email me a link to the thread when it shows up, but for now i'm trying to keep it basic and have the script return the line that contains my keyword.

Comment: Hello Jennifer, so to the issue is each thread has a different xpath. So putting each thread's path won't work. Can you please try the solution I edited? Because that gets all the text from the threads and split using "R:". This is because if you look into that website each thread starts with "R:". Also, please make sure that the thread is returned irrespective of the case. Meaning "doge" should also be accepted and not just "DOGE". Thank You.

Comment: It will work if you use an xpath with contains like this: //div[@id='threads']/div[contains(@id,'thread')] . To check without case match, just add .lower() to the searchText array. I'll fix that in my post.